# How do you tell if IIS is I/O bound?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis

Running IIS 6 on Windows 2003 server (with a web service app). I suspect the machine is network I/O bound.

I'm hearing reports of errors - but not seeing those errors in the IIS logs.

What is the standard way of verifying this? Is there a counter in perfmon?

Thanks for the help.

[Edit: modified to clarify I/O type - network]

Comment: Which type of I/O? Disk? Network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For disk IO: Disk Queue Length being consistently high, while CPU and Memory are not saturated would be a very strong indicator.

Comment: Thanks. Is there something similar for network I/O too?

Comment: @christopherstott: The networking tab of task manager is good for a quick look to see if your NICs are max'ed out. There are plenty of counters to get into the details of networking.